# jQuery - Como pegar o primeiro caracter de um input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um input que quero criar validações personalizadas, necessito pegar seu valor e fazer validações referente ao primeiro caracter do input, qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: `var primeiro = input.value[0];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pegue o valor do input e utilize a função charAt com a posição do caractere no caso 0.

```
var valor = $('#id_input').val();
alert(valor.charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 4):

Versão sem jQuery.

Porque não é necessário jQuery pra isso.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input1');
const primeiro = input.value[0];
console.log(primeiro);
```

```html
<input id="input1" type="text" value="um monte de texto" />
```

Comment: Depende, a questão nisto nem é o jQuery, mas sim o uso de `charAt` ou `[...]`, ou seja no geral *"não está usando jQuery"*, se a pessoa já usa jQuery pra outras coisas não vejo mal algum em `$(...).val();`, então basta fazer o teste `console.log("foo"[0]);`. Concorda que em nenhuma das respostas foi de fato o jQuery que fez algo?